# Implementing Web Client call using PUT method against JWPlayer

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I am implementing a Web Client call to JWPlayer Management API.  I have successfully created a Web Client call using there non-accelerated upload method.  I am now trying to implement a PUT call using WebClient to there S3 accelerated Upload method.

```
/*The documentation states:
Two-step process
S3 file upload is done using a two-step process:
First, /videos/create or /videos/update API call is done. The call     will return an upload URL. 
*/
```

Second, the file is submitted to this upload URL using HTTP PUT method.

```
/*Upload URL
Response of the create or update API call includes a link block   with parameters that should be used to construct the upload URL. For example, response of the /videos/create API call:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
  <status>ok</status>
  <video key="tL17msiU">
    <link>
      <protocol>https</protocol>
      <address>upload-s3.jwplatform.com</address>
      <path>/tL17msiU</path>
      <query>
        <AWSAccessKeyId>AKIAIRXCJ3TPZA4HVNYZ</AWSAccessKeyId>
        <Expires>1482770374</Expires>
        <Signature>1/l+L6/yOE05dNEbXHW8sw7TGF4=</Signature>
      </query>
    </link>
  </video>
</response>
*/
```

The upload URL should be concatenated from the parts of the link block using the following scheme:

```
upload_url = <link/protocol> + "://" + <link/address> + <link/path> +
"?AWSAccessKeyId=" + <link/query/AWSAccessKeyId> +
"&Expires=" + <link/query/Expires> +
"&Signature=" + urlencode(<link/query/Signature>)
```

That should produce the following upload URL using response example from above:

```
https://upload-s3.jwplatform.com/tL17msiU
?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIRXCJ3TPZA4HVNYZ
&Expires=1482770374
&Signature=1%2Fl%2BL6%2FyOE05dNEbXHW8sw7TGF4%3D
```

Uploading File

After upload URL has been constructed, it can be used to upload file using, for example, curl tool:

```
/*
curl --request PUT --upload-file /file_path/file_name.mp4 \
"https://upload-s3.jwplatform.com  /tL17msiU?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIRXCJ3TPZA4HVNYZ&Expires=1482770374&  Signature=1%2Fl%2BL6%2FyOE05dNEbXHW8sw7TGF4%3D"***
*/
```

I have successfully generated the upload URL, but I'm having trouble replacing the curl call typically done in PHP with a .NET webClient call.  I have tried webClient.UploadString and WebClient.UpdateData but I keep getting a Invalid Request format 404 error.  My code is:

```
//Ignore this line, this simply uses a 3rd party tool to generate the upload URL
BotRAPI api = new BotR.API.BotRAPI("xxx", "yyy");

//params to store with a new video
NameValueCollection col = new NameValueCollection() {                    
{"up load_method", "s3"}
};

//create the new video
string xml = api.Call("/videos/create", col);

XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var result = (from d in doc.Descendants("status")
select new
{
   Status = d.Value
).FirstOrDefault();

//make sure the status was "ok" before trying to upload
if (result.Status.Equals("ok",    StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnore Case))
{

    var response = doc.Descendants("link").FirstOrDefault();
    String url = string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}",      response.Element("protocol").Value, response.Element("address").Value,    response.Element("path").Value);

response = doc.Descendants("query").FirstOrDefault();
url = string.Format(url + "?AWSAccessKeyId={0}&Expires={1}&   Signature={2}", response.Element("AWSAccessKeyId").Value,     response.Element("Expires").Value, response.Element("Signature").Value);

}
```

I then try to initiate the PUT call using WebClient:

```
string filePath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "test.mp4");

byte[] data = ReadAllBytes(FilePath);

MyWebClient client = WebClient();
client.UploadData(url,data);
```